# How to reinstall / repair entire Debian through rescue mode after upgrade failure without wipe the disk?

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg, debian-installer, debootstrap

I followed [this wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianUpgrade) tried to upgrade Debian 10 to 11 then 12, but form some reason some part messed up the system and now it can't boot (kernel panic) and entire system messed up: no `apt` available, no `vi` available etc.

I am trying to use Debian 12 installer to repair it, trying to use its rescue mode to reinstall OS.

What I tried was:

1. Boot rescue mode with boot disk and try to install minimum dependency like `apt` but it doesn't work. Too much dependencies
2. Then it am working with the `debootstrap` try to reinstall the target disk, but stuck at "Chosen extractor for .deb packages: ar" and failed.

What is the best way to reinstall and/or repair this entire Debian OS and make the old OS working again?

Comment: I think the best path forward is (a) back up your data, (b) re-install a fresh environment, then (c) restore your data. You don't know what state things are in right now so any sort of "fix things until it works" recovery process is going to be difficult.